How to use User Defined Type(UDT) in dapper for oracle databse
I have a UDT like
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VList AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100); 

and this is my stored procedure;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SEND_EMAIL_PROC
(
P_EmployeeIds VList,
P_DeptsIds VList,
P_SEND_DEPTS VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'T'
)
IS
BEGIN
    ..logic here
END
END SEND_EMAIL_PROC;

I have backend code like:
public async Task<bool> SendMail(List<string> emIds, List<string> deptsIds)
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
 
        using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SEND_EMAIL_PROC", connection))
        {
            OracleParameter paramUDT = new OracleParameter();
            paramUDT.ParameterName = "P_EmployeeIds ";
            paramUDT.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            paramUDT.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            paramUDT.Value = emIds;
            paramUDT.Size = emIds.Length;

            // Add the UDT parameter to the command
            command.Parameters.Add(paramUDT);

            OracleParameter paramUDT1 = new OracleParameter();
            paramUDT1.ParameterName = "P_DeptsIds";
            paramUDT1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            paramUDT1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            paramUDT1.Value = deptsIds;
            paramUDT1.Size = deptsIds.Length;

            // Add the UDT parameter to the command
            command.Parameters.Add(paramUDT1);

            // Create the OracleParameter for the regular parameter and set its properties
            OracleParameter paramRegular = new OracleParameter();
            paramRegular.ParameterName = "P_SEND_DEPTS ";
            paramRegular.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            paramRegular.Value = "T";

            // Add the regular parameter to the command
            command.Parameters.Add(paramRegular);

            // Execute the stored procedure
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

While calling SendMail() function, the code throws an error:

wrong or types of arguments in call to SEND_EMAIL_PROC

I'm using C# with Dapper along with Oracle.
